# ValueError in pandas: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace my values in the title column of my dataframe. However. Its throwing error

```
for i in range(0, 1309):
    if((x['Title'][i])=='Mr'):
        x['Title'][i] = '0'
    if(x['Title'][i]=='Miss'):
        x['Title'][i] = '1'
    if(x['Title'][i]=='Mrs'):
        x['Title'][i] = '2'
    if(x['Title'][i]=='Master'):
        x['Title'][i] = '3'
    else:
        x['Title'][i] = '4'
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You want to rename the column?

Comment: I want to replace all the data in title column with 1 and so on

Comment: what are all the possible values of Title??

Comment: There are many. But I want to replace those with 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this create a dictionary of names substitutions like this :

```
names ={'Mr':0, 'Miss':1, 'Master':2, 'Mrs':3}
```

And use replace to renames those values :

```
df['Title'] = df.Title.replace(names).replace({'': 4})
```

UPDATE :
Solution 2 you cloud use apply function

```
def change_names(x):
    if x == 'Mr':
        return 0
    elif x =='Miss':
        return 1
    elif x == 'Master':
        return 2
    elif x =='Mrs':
        return 3
    else:
        return 4

df['Title'] = df['Title'].apply(change_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.rename(columns = {'Mr':'0'}, inplace = True)
```

and add other columns